# How to Join on All Columns Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

If I have two tables in Scala Spark how can I join on every column without explicitly writing it out. Here would be the method where I would have to write out every column. I would like to use the Seq method as it removes duplicate columns.

```
table("a")
.join(table("b", Seq("col_a","col_b"....)
```

Comment: You're selecting column `a` and joining to column `b` using a bunch of non-existent columns. Could you clarify what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DataFrame.columns` to get all columns, if they are same for both the tables/data frames then you can join them as following. If the column names are different then you need custom logic to build the join condition.

```
    case class atable(column1:String, column2:String)

    val table1 = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(atable(column1 = "a",column2 = "1"),atable(column1 = "b",column2 = "2")))
    val table2 = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(atable(column1 = "a",column2 = "1"),atable(column1 = "c",column2 = "3")))

    table1.join(table2, table1.columns).show()
```

Result -

```
+-------+-------+
|column1|column2|
+-------+-------+
|      a|      1|
+-------+-------+
```